# Memoir: force page numbers on blank even pages

Tags: header-footer, memoir, page-numbering

I'm using the `memoir` class to write a thesis. My institution's thesis formatting handbook requires page numbers on any blank even-numbered pages that may appear before chapters and other divisions that need to start on an odd-numbered page, **except** on the page right after the title page and before the first frontmatter section ("Abstract"), which has to be numbered "iii".

The "except" bit is the default behavior of `memoir`, but for the other frontmatter divisions (Table of Contents, List of Figures, List of Tables, Acknowledgements) as well as the chapters and appendices of the mainmatter, I haven't been able to find a solution. (Therefore, no MWE.)

Is there any way to force `\pagestlye{plain}` into for example `\clearforchapter` or `\cleardoublepage`?

Comment: Just alias cleared (I think that's the name) to plain in frontmatter, and when mainmatter starters alias it back to empty. See the manual.

Comment: I think I need a little more detailed instructions. I know the passage of the manual (I think), but I don't know what \cleardoublepage is supposed to be doing...

Comment: At vacation, so no pc. In memoir cleardoublepage runs the cleared (or what it is called) page style on the blank page. That style is an alias for empty. But you can change the target for the style using aliaspagestyle new old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer by daleif in the comment on the question was, indeed, correct. Since I found this a hard-to-search-for issue, I'll write it down here and answer my own question this way. The crucial trick is to use `\aliaspagestyle`. After my abstract, that is, at the point from which on I want empty even-numbered pages to show the number, I use:

```
\aliaspagestyle{cleared}{plain}
```

This is explained in section 7.3 (p. 109f) of the manual for the `memoir` class (v3.7f, 2016-05-16).